# How to check if an Javascript script has been loaded Asynchronously (Async) or async attribute is present?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, asynchronous, callback

I would like know if there exists a handy way to check if an script (on execution) has been loaded asynchronously.

E.g. 
the script tag:

```
<script async type="text/javascript" src="js/async.js"></script>
```

the script async.js:

```
if (_condition_to_check_if_this_has_been_loaded_async) { console.log("async: true") }
```

Comment: Is that `async.js` your script or some script you do not have access to and cannot modify?

Comment: Angelos yes, is my script.

Comment: You could define a variable to check for from the other script or you can do what I suggest in my answer as a general case. Hope that was helpful to you! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless you want `IE` compatibility, the correct answer to this problem is using the little-known but widely supported [`document.currentScript`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/currentScript) property.

This property returns the `HTMLScriptElement` of the script currently being executed (or nothing if the script isn't in a tag/is a callback or similar), which tells you if it has the `async`/`defer` attributes, among other things.

The MDN example even cites this exact use-case:

```
if (document.currentScript.async) {
  console.log("Executing asynchronously");
} else {
  console.log("Executing synchronously");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try to test if document source is loaded:

```
if (document.readyState == "complete" || document.readyState == "loaded") {
     // script was fired async
} else {
    // script was sync
}
```

it might work because if script is fired synchronously then `document.readyState` won't be `complete` or `loaded` at the execution time

however, if your script is small then it might load before the whole page was parsed, so it is not an ideal solution, but worth mentioning in my opinion

Comment: I did tried your proposition, unfortunately, the script I'm trying to work around is added via `element.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", "<script async src="assets/js/async.js"></script>");` I did added your example to the script and seems is not working as you said.

Answer (score 0):

**jQuery:**

You can use `jQuery` to select all `script` elements in the page, then check if their `src` attribute matches the one you are looking for. Example below contains a check for your script (loaded) and another one (not loaded) to show you the results od checking in both cases:

```js
var len = $('script').filter(function () {
    return ($(this).attr('src') == 'js/async.js');
}).length;
if (len === 0) console.log('async not found');
else console.log('async found');
var len = $('script').filter(function () {
    return ($(this).attr('src') == 'js/foobar.js');
}).length;
if (len === 0) console.log('foobar not found');
else console.log('foobar found');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script async type="text/javascript" src="js/async.js"></script>
```

**Pure Javascript:**

Alternatively, you can use pure Javascript, utilising the `getElementsByTagName()` and `getAttribute()` methods to achieve the same thing. Example below:

```js
var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName('script');
var found = false;
for(var i = 0; i<scripts.length; i++)
  if(scripts[i].getAttribute('src')=='js/async.js')
    found = true;
if (found) console.log('async found');
else console.log('async not found');

var scripts2 = document.getElementsByTagName('script');
var found = false;
for(var i = 0; i<scripts.length; i++)
  if(scripts2[i].getAttribute('src')=='js/foobar.js')
    found = true;
if (found) console.log('foobar found');
else console.log('foobar not found');
```

```html
 <script async type="text/javascript" src="js/async.js"></script>
```

**UPDATE:** If you want to check if the `js/async.js` script has been loaded and also if it has the attribute `async`, you can use a similar techinque. Examples below:

**jQuery:**

```js
var len = $('script').filter(function () {
    return ($(this).attr('src') == 'js/async.js' && $(this).attr('async')!== typeof undefined && $(this).attr('async') !== false);
}).length;
if (len === 0) console.log('async not found');
else console.log('async found');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script async type="text/javascript" src="js/async.js"></script>
```

**Pure Javascript:**

```js
var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName('script');
var found = false;
for(var i = 0; i<scripts.length; i++)
  if(
    scripts[i].getAttribute('src')=='js/async.js' 
    && scripts[i].getAttribute('async')!= typeof undefined)
    found = true;
if (found) console.log('async found');
else console.log('async not found');
```

```html
<script async type="text/javascript" src="js/async.js"></script>
```