# Cross site issue with Microsoft Graph Toolkit

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, cross-site

I'm following [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/toolkit/get-started/build-a-web-app?tabs=html%2CHTML) to create a simple web app with a Microsoft 365 login.  I'm currently getting this error when debugging locally (http://localhost:8080):

Warning:

> mgt-loader.js:61   A parser-blocking, cross site (i.e. different eTLD+1) script, https://unpkg.com/@microsoft/mgt/dist/bundle/wc/webcomponents-loader.js, is invoked via document.write. The network request for this script MAY be blocked by the browser in this or a future page load due to poor network connectivity. If blocked in this page load, it will be confirmed in a subsequent console message. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5718547946799104 for more details.

In Azure, I have the Redirect URIs set up to match (http://localhost:8080).

After some googling, I tried adding `async`, but then I get this warning and the login button doesn't appear:

> mgt-loader.js:61  Failed to execute 'write' on 'Document': It isn't possible to write into a document from an asynchronously-loaded external script unless it is explicitly opened.

What would be causing this warning and how can I fix it?

Comment: Can you share which browser are you using? I didn't see any problem when trying with Chrome/edge. Also, the guide you mentioned asks you to use Live server. Is that what you are using?

Comment: I'm using Edge. And yes, I'm using Live Server in VS Code.

Comment: the bundle url I have seen in the guide is "https://unpkg.com/@microsoft/mgt/dist/bundle/mgt-loader.js

Comment: That is the URL I am using. This is the very first line in the `head` of my HTML:  `<script src="https://unpkg.com/@microsoft/mgt/dist/bundle/mgt-loader.js"></script>`

Comment: why not try npm option from the guide instead of using unpkg.com.

Comment: Issue might be unpkg.com related for you. I tried downloading the the 3 files locally and referencing them and that works as well:                               
mgt-app\wc\webcomponents-loader.js
mgt-app\mgt-loader.js
mgt-app\mgt.es6.js

  <!-- and in html just replace the unpkg.com with the path to mgt-loader.js-->
  <script src="mgt-loader.js"></script>

Comment: Yes, now that I understand the answer from @Łukasz Szcześniak that is the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, check out how `document.write` works: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write

You will understand why you cannot run `document.write` in asynchronous context (try running `document.write('Hello world!');` in console on any page).

Warning tells you that a parser blocking (synchronous), cross site (not coming from the same domain as website) scripts can be blocked by Chrome in the future if someone has unstable or bad internet connection.

If you want it to run synchronously without that warning, you have to bundle that JS code with your own, or just serve it from your own origin, same as your website (e.g. `localhost:8080`). You can download `@microsoft/mgt` npm package and for bundling - use gulp, webpack or other tool of your choice.

https://unpkg.com/@microsoft/mgt@2.4.0/dist/bundle/wc/webcomponents-loader.js

This script tries to differentiate between async and sync contexts (line 175) and run `document.appendChild` (instead of `write`) for async context - but for some reason the check fails (`readyState === loading`).

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/readyState

[How to check if an Javascript script has been loaded Asynchronously (Async) or async attribute is present?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38370089/how-to-check-if-an-javascript-script-has-been-loaded-asynchronously-async-or-a)

If you want to run this in non-blocking manner, you could try to fix the script by yourself.

There is a Github repo for that toolkit (https://www.npmjs.com/package/@microsoft/mgt), but there is no issue regarding async loading, nor regarding the warning that you have noticed - so maybe nobody else has noticed or thought about it yet.

Comment: A bit of a misunderstanding on my part, but also a bit of "TMI" on your part (IMO). Now that I reread it, the answer is "This is going to happen when using a CDN for this package. To get rid of the error you can use the NPM package and serve it from your host. To understand why this error happens, here is some more info..."

Comment: Please make a minor edit (at least) and I will rescind the downvote.